# Different data type lengths in third party libraries

Tags: c++, c, types, compilation, linker

Both C and C++ standards do not specify the exact length of some data types, only their minimum lengths.

I have a third party library: `someLib.lib` (compiled for my platform) and its corresponding `someLib.h`. Let's say it contains the following functions:

```
int getNumber();
void setNumber(int number);
```

When I compile a program consuming this library, the compiler checks the types with the signatures defined in the `someLib.h`, so as long as I use `int`s, everything should compile fine.

But what happens when in my compiler's `int` is longer or shorter than in the compiler that was used compile `someLib.lib`? Will it be detected during linking? Will it cause runtime errors? Can I safely use the `someLib.lib` without knowing how it was compiled?

Comment: That's almost never a problem with simple types such as `int`.  Where this kind of issue shows up is with structures that have different padding depending on compiler differences or even just different options on the same compiler; or with features that have implementation-defined details such as bit fields.  That's one reason to have opaque interfaces that contain such details entirely within the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not get compiler or linker errors, only undefined behavior at run-time. Possibly crashes, or if you're lucky just weird results.

Comment: I'd say you are lucky if you get crashes and unlucky if you get only weird results.

Answer (score 1):

Using a library that has narrow assumptions about the underlying system or the compiler can cause problems.

So, if the library that you're using has assumed that `int` is 16 bit but you're using it in a 32 bit system, you'll have problems in run-time.

Good implemented libraries have `#if` macros to minimize these issues, or they've implemented various `.lib` files for different systems. They could even explicitly use `intX_t` (e.g. `int32_t`) integers to be more portable.